# MySQL Replication Monitoring for OS X Server

Tags: monitoring, mac-osx-server, mysql-replication

I have a CentOS 5 MySQL 5.0 server running that I need to replicate. I will setup MYSQL on OS X (Mac mini), but what tool should I use to monitor the replication that runs on OS X?